# Huge memory leak with long-lived subscription to an Rx Subject

Tags: c#, queue, system.reactive

I have implemented what is probably an extremely naive in-memory fan-out queuing mechanism like so:

```cs
public class ObservableQueue<T> : IObservableQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Subject<T> queue;

    public IObservable<T> Messages => queue.AsObservable();

    public ObservableQueue()
    {
        queue = new Subject<T>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        queue.OnNext(item);
    }

    public void Enqueue(List<T> items)
    {
        items.ForEach(queue.OnNext);
    }
}
```

The reason I chose for this implementation is that it allows for extremely expressive subscriptions, which I'm a huge fan of, like so:

```cs
subscription = queue.Messages
    .Select(data => data.ToJson())
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), ByteSize.FromBytes(128))
    .Where(Enumerable.Any)
    .Select(ToQuery)
    .Subscribe(query => db.Execute(query));
```

The `Buffer` method used here is, once again, a somewhat naive implementation by me:

```cs
public static IObservable<IList<string>> Buffer(this IObservable<string> source, TimeSpan timeSpan, ByteSize size) 
{
    // Completes when the `timespan` has elapsed
    var timer = Observable.Timer(timeSpan).Select(_ => new Unit());
    // Completes when the ByteSize exceeds `size`
    var bytes = source
        .Scan(ByteSize.FromBytes(0),
                    (a, b) => a + ByteSize.FromBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(b)))
        .SkipWhile(a => a < size)
        .Select(_ => new Unit()); // We only want to use these for notification, and both observables
                                  // need to be of the same type, so we just emit Unit

    // Amb races the two observables to see which one finishes first, which then propagates the notification
    // and signals the source to strop buffering
    return source.Buffer(() => Observable.Amb(timer, bytes));
}
```

Now, as soon as I create the subscription in the second code block, there is an absolute explosion in memory usage, the culprit being the `Subject<T>` in the `ObservableQueue<T>`. I should stress that at that point, not actual data has been `Enqueue`d. The `subscription` has been created and is still waiting for any data to actually work on.

I can see some potential culprits here:

- `queue.AsObservable()`
- The custom `Buffer` method I wrote
- The fact that the `subscription` is long-lived

Yet I've not been able to pinpoint the actual root-cause here. Any ideas?

Note: I think it's pretty obvious I'm not very well acquainted with `System.Reactive` so I do apologize if I wrote anything silly here.

Comment: I should probably point out that I'm running .NET Core 2.2 and System.Reactive 4.1.3

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows the issue you're facing?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'll give it a shot

Comment: Cannot reproduce the explosion of memory usage. I used an instance of your ObservableQueue your extension method and the same subscription without the db-stuff. ByteSize 1.3, Reactive 4.1.5  & .Net 4.6.1